# В чем ошибка? Почему не показывает массив?

Tags: android

```
Resources res = getResources();
String apple = res.getString(R.string.word_apple);
String girl = res.getString(R.string.word_girl);
String man = res.getString(R.string.word_man);
String boy = res.getString(R.string.word_boy);
String family = res.getString(R.string.word_family);
String child = res.getString(R.string.word_child);
private String[] questions = {"", girl, man, boy, family, child, apple, ""};
count = 0;
```

> И метод OnClickListener

```
    Button butCheck = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    butCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
    if(count<8){
    count++;
    textView.setText(questoins[count]);
    }else{
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, Second.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
    }
```

Comment: А причем здесь ArrayList???

Comment: Что за `count`? Где он инициализируется?

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, `ArrayList` я тут не вижу. В приведенном коде есть только обычный массив `String[] questions`.

Во-вторых, данный код не скомпилируется, ибо в в строке:

```
textView.setText(questoins[count])
```

нет точки с запятой.

Ну а в-третьих, по очередному нажатию кнопки в `textView` будет отображаться соответствующий элемент массива только если Вы измените:

```
textView.setText(questoins[count])
```

на

```
textView.setText(questions[count]);
```

Ну и еще в приведенном коде куча проблем.